# Раздвоение класса python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def b(self, n):
        self -= A(n)
        print(self)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return A(self.a - other.a)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'class A a={self.a}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(100)
    a.b(10)
    print(a)
```

Вывод

```
class A a=90
class A a=100
```

Не могу понять почему метод b вычитает 10 из какого-то дубликата класса, а сам класс остается неизменным?

Pycharm предупреждает, что `Method's parameter 'self' reassigned`, то есть что self переназначается, но я не могу понять почему это происходит

Comment: Потому что в методе `__sub__` Вы возвращаете новый класс, не изменяя текущий.

Comment: у вас вывод неточный. снача принтуется  а.б в методе и только патом само а в последней строке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как написали в комментариях:

> Потому что в методе `__sub__` Вы возвращаете новый класс, не изменяя текущий. Вот пример изменения экземпляра класса:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def b(self, n):
        self -= A(n)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        self.a -= other.a
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return f'class A a={self.a}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(100)
    a.b(10)
    print(a)
```

Comment: Все таки я не очень понимаю. Метод __sub__ должен вызываться например в таком случае ```result = A(5) - A(3)```. Тогда вместо ```A(5) - A(3)``` будет новый экземпляр класса, и он будет присвоен в result. Но в случае ```result -= A(4)``` разве не должен вызываться метод __isub__? У меня он не определен, но питон вроде сам может получить его если определен __sub__

Comment: `self -= A(n)` - подобная запись не изменяет экземпляр класса. Более подробно можно прочитать тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216356/is-it-safe-to-replace-a-self-object-by-another-object-of-the-same-type-in-a-meth

Answer (score 1):

> Pycharm предупреждает, что Method's parameter 'self' reassigned, то есть что self переназначается, но я не могу понять почему это происходит

вы сами написали:

> ```
> self -= A(n)
> ```

@nomnoms12:

> Потому что в методе `__sub__` Вы возвращаете новый класс, не изменяя текущий.